# Searching the closest but "less than or equal to" values in other column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Suppose we have a data frame of two columns

```
 X    Y 
 9   11
 10  14   
 13  17  
 17  20   
 21  23
```

For the first element of Y, that is 11, the closest but "less than or equal to" in X is 10 (which is 2nd element of X). Similarly, For next element of Y, that is 14, the closest but "less than or equal to" is 13 that is 3rd element of X

So, the output should be

```
2
3
4
4
5
```

As my data is large, Can you suggest me the right way to do it ?
 (Note: Max of "less than or equal to " is same as "the closest but less than or equal to")

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Why is, in the case of 14, the max of "less than or equal to" 13. Isn't it 14?

Comment: If `df$X` is ordered, a simple `findInterval(df$Y,df$X)` should work.

Comment: @nicola if you can't find a dupe you should probably post it.